# ios - how to determine if a cell indexPath changed in uitableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two questions :

1- Is it possible to know if a cell `indexPath.row` has changed in a `UITableView` ? for example if I have an element at **index (0)** and then I add another one, the first element will be at **index (1)**. Is it possible to detect this change ?

2- Is it possible to fnd the index of an element by the cell title ? for example I have X,Y,Z element in the tableview and I want to know in which cell 'X' is placed ?

thanks guys,

Comment: what do you mean by 1) ? Wouldn't you be adding the cell, so you would be able to detect the change if any depending on how you inserted a cell.

Comment: Don't do anything using the cells. Do everything through your data model.

Comment: @JoshHamet for example I have a table view contains "cell A" at index 0 and I add a second one "cell B" which will be added on the top of the table view so it will be at index 0 and "cell B" at index 1. I want to know if there's a way to detect that "cell A" index has changed from index 0 to index 1

Comment: @sam well since you added it, wouldn't you know it moved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's common practice to isolate model and view. What I mean by this, is separate the storage of the data and the view that's rendering it.

For example, you may be creating a table view of color names. Therefore, you could store an array of color names as a property of your view controller

```
class UIColorViewController: UITableViewController{

    let colors = ["Black", "Blue", "Yellow"]
```

As I'm sure you're doing, you can assign the view controller as the data source of the table view so you can tell it how many sections you want, the number of rows you want in a section, and what to render onto a cell.

In this elementary example, the number of sections could be 1 and the number of rows in this section would be the length of the colors array. Now when rendering data onto the cell, you simply index the colors array by the index path.

```
fun tableView(UITableView, cellForRowAt: IndexPath){
    var color = colors[indexPath.row]
    cell = //dequeue cell
    cell.textLabel?.text = color
    return cell
}
```

So by separating the data from the view, if you want to find what cell a particular value is at, you can simply search through the array where the color is at and the index returned would be equivalent to what cell this color is or will be at depending on if that cell has been rendered onto the screen yet.

For example using the colors array, if I were looking for "Blue"

```
for (index, color) in self.colors.enumerated{
    if color == 'Blue'{
        print("Found Blue at index \(index)")
    }
 }
```

When you want to add a cell or delete a cell, you simply modify the colors array which is storing the model data, perform the appropriate table view related action, and the invariant remains that the index of the color in the array would be equivalent to the index of the cell in the table view.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That's what I'm doing (separating the model and view) and I can find the value of a cell by its index. until here everything is ok.
But you said : "you can simply search through the array where the color is at and the index returned" if I get your point, that means there's a way to return an index by searching in the array ?

Comment: @sam Yes, you can simply iterate over every element in the array and when you find the element you're looking for, record its index.

Comment: is it possible to me provide an example ? with the colors array for example. thanks a lot Josh

Comment: @sam I just edited my answer and provided a simple example